# Socket data sending right but receiving altered

Tags: c, sockets

I have a client program that connects to two servers at the same time. To serialize the data I'm transferring  through the sockets I created the following `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    char origin[14];
    char type;
    char data[100];
}socket_data;
```

When connecting the client process to the servers, the client sends some information and waits to receive a response by both servers:

**Client:**

```
//...

//Sending info to both servers
socket_data station_info;
strcpy(station_info.origin, "DANNY");
station_info.type = 'C';
strcpy(station_info.data, config.station);

write(socket_jack, &station_info, sizeof(socket_data));
write(socket_wendy, &station_info, sizeof(socket_data));

//Getting servers response
socket_data response_jack, response_wendy;
read(socket_jack, &response_jack, sizeof(socket_data));
read(socket_wendy, &response_wendy, sizeof(socket_data));

/*DEBUGGING*/char str[150]; sprintf(str, "%s, %c, %s\n", response_jack.origin, response_jack.type, response_jack.data);write(1, str, strlen(str));
/*DEBUGGING*/char st[150]; sprintf(st, "%s, %c, %s\n", response_wendy.origin, response_wendy.type, response_wendy.data);write(1, st, strlen(st));

//...
```

**Server 1 & Server 2 (same code for both):**

```
//...

//Receiving clients info
socket_data station_info;
read(socket, &station_info, sizeof(socket_data));

//Sending a response to the client
if (station_info.type != 'C') {
    socket_data response;
    strcpy(response.origin, "JACK");
    response.type = 'E';
    strcpy(response.data, "ERROR");

    write(socket, &response, sizeof(socket_data));

    close(socket);

    return 0;
} else {
    socket_data response;
    strcpy(response.origin, "JACK");
    response.type = 'O';
    strcpy(response.data, "CONNECTION OK");

    /*DEBUGGING*/char str[150]; sprintf(str, "%s, %c, %s\n", response.origin, response.type, response.data); write(1, str, strlen(str));
    write(socket, &response, sizeof(socket_data));
}
```

As you can see, I've added some `writes` for debugging purposes and when I execute the code, the ideal output I expect on the client side is:

```
JACK, O, CONNECTION OK
WENDY, O, CONNECTION OK
```

But instead, I'm getting something like:

```
, C, TION OK
WENDY, O, CONNECTION OK
```

or

```
JACK, O, CONNECTION OK
, C, TION OK
```

and sometimes it won't even print anything.

I'm guessing the socket buffer needs to be cleared up, but I'm not sure if that's the solution in here. How can I fix this or clear the socket buffer?

Comment: `read()` and `write()` both return a value. Use it.

Comment: @wildplasser I don't see how can I use the return values of bytes by `read` or `write` in this case... any hint?

Comment: You could loop up in the manual their actual meaning. In both cases, it can differ from the value of the third argument that the caller supplied.

Comment: Just because you ask to read or write X bytes doesn't mean that many will actually be read or written. Hence the need to use their return values.

Comment: Then I'll need to calculate the exact amount of bytes to be transferred before the respective `write` or `read` and add the amount to the third argument instead of `sizeof(socket_data)` as I have now?

Comment: @user157629 No.  Since both `read()` and `write()` can return fewer bytes than requested, you need to call them both in a loop until you have received/sent all of the bytes you are expecting. For example, say you are expecting 100 bytes from `read()` and only 50 bytes are received, you will need to call `read()` again to read the remaining 50 bytes. Same with `write()`. That is where their return values come into play. They tell you the actual bytes received/sent. Subtract that from the requested size, and if the result is > 0 then call the function again with parameters adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example for the comments above.

```
socket_data station_info;

char *buf = (char*) &station_info;
size_t len = sizeof(socket_data);

while (len > 0) {
    ssize_t res = read(socket_jack, buf, len); //or write
    if (res == -1) {
        printf("io error.\n");
        exit(-1); //only for test purpose, will exit the program here
    }
    buf += res; //increase the buffer position
    len -= res; //decrease the remaining number of bytes
}
```

Comment: Seems like when it loops and executes the `read` again, it blocks (maybe waiting for another `write` even tho I'm debugging and the `write` sends 115/115 bytes already. Any clue?

Comment: How does it behaves, if you execute it normally (not in the debugger)? Still blocking? Result of io operation > 0 and != -1? How many bytes do you read in the first step? 115 (sizeof(struct))? Better you append your code to the question and let us have a look.